# Django admin generates static url with /admin/ prefixed

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-urls, django-grappelli

I'm trying to setup a second development environment for my project. I've copied over the settings from the working setup but on the new one the URLs generated by the Django admin are prefixed with `/admin/`. This does not happen with the other setup at all.

More details:

- I'm using **django-grappelli** for my admin panel.
- The generated urls on the **working** setup are of the kind `/static/grappelli` while on the **not-working** one they are of the kind `/admin/static/grappelli`.
- Disabling grappelli yields no fix either, the urls are then of the kind `/admin/static/admin`.
- I'm using Django 1.5, it uses a git repository for the source files and a frozen pip `requirements.txt`. I can only conclude that version differences are highly unlikely.
- Other static files work fine, only the admin related ones are hit with this.

My URL settings are the following:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/static/media/'
```

The ***_ROOT** ones are not set due to use of development server.

I'm out of ideas as to why this is happening on only one of the servers with the same setup.

**edit:**
Removing the `/admin/` prefix allows you to properly access the files. The finder is fine, but the urls generated are just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is very simple, the `STATIC_URL` setting should always contain the first `/`. It seems the Django admin prepends `/admin/` if there is none.

I had a faulty settings file overwriting my default `STATIC_URL`, always check your settings first!